# scrollTo top of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

lets say I have this:

```
var infoBox = $(".info");
```

lets say then I am expanding one `infoBox` and I want the document to scroll to the top of that `infoBox` sot hat I can see its whole content.

I know i should first find the offset, the distance of `infoBox` from the top and left of the document and I also know `offset()` returns `top` and `left`.

Is this what should do then?

```
var offset = infoBox.offset();
$(document).scrollTo(offset.top);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost!

```
var offset = infoBox.offset();
$(document).scrollTop(offset.top);
```

See [jQuery.scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).

Comment: pardon? is it not the same? :)

Comment: No - you had "scrollTo", which is not in jQuery, but in a plugin. I suggested "scrollTop", which is in jQuery. There is also a link to the relevant documentation in the answer.

Comment: okey dokey, yes, right i will just go with the standard jQuery no plug in required in my case i guess. Thanks, will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do (if you are referring to [this](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin)

```
$(document).scrollTo(offset);
```

Comment: if i try that happens exactly what happens in my example above, i get the top of the content div cut off

Comment: Using that plugin, I think you could just do $(document).scrollTo(".info").

Answer (score 0):

I eventually had to use position() rather than offset()

```
var offset = item.position().top;
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:offset}, 500);
```

and use this for cross browsers:

```
$("html, body")
```